# Unity new particle system conversion

Tags: unity-game-engine

I tried to convert old unity particle emitter to new shuriken system. Here is what i do so far;

Before Conversion;

```
private Particle[] particles;

void Start()
{
    oneOverZigs = 1f / (float)zigs;
    particleEmitter.emit = false;

    particleEmitter.Emit(zigs);
    particles = particleEmitter.particles;
}
```

After Conversion;

```
private ParticleSystem.Particle[] particles;

void Start()
{

    oneOverZigs = 1f / (float)zigs;

    GetComponent<ParticleEmitter>().emit = false; --> Particle Emitter doesn't contain  'emit'

    GetComponent<ParticleEmitter>().Emit(zigs); -->  Particle Emitter doesn't contain  'Emit'

    particles = GetComponent<ParticleEmitter>().particles; -->  Particle Emitter doesn't contain  'particles'


}
```

I specified errors above code. I couldn't convert much more. How can i convert 3 lines to new system?

Comment: They are almost entirely different things, so I don't think there has an easy way to convert.

Comment: i just got back after 6-7 years to making game.so when i return, i am kinda shocked:)